# How to find the number of ways to split a array into 2 equal subsets?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I need to find the number of ways to split the array into 2 equal subsets (not necessarily all elements must be in at least one of the subsets). The array contains numbers from $1$ to $N$. For example: $[1,2,3,4,4,4]$. Subsets suitable for the example: $[4]_{4} [4]_{5}$ $[4]_{4} [4]_{6}$ $[4]_{5} [4]_{6}$ and answer is 3.
There may be identical sets in the answer, because we take elements from different positions.
I had a solution, I will describe it briefly:
let $F(с)$ be the number of occurrence in the array of the value C,
then let $p = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left\lfloor{F(x)\over 2}\right\rfloor$.

Then the answer can be calculated as: $$\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k} = 2^p  - 1$$

But when the number of occurrences of some values > 2, the solution falls.

Can anyone tell me if I'm thinking in the right direction?
Or give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't find how to write rounding down, for this I used the floor function in the formula description

Comment: You introduce a function $F$ that you will not use anywhere and then you set $p$ depending from $x$ that has never been defined. Also $N$ should be defined as well (I think it is $N := \#Set $) and even the set of the example you give has no $5$ in it.
Please, update your question with all the right notations

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice some typos.Already fixed my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you are really looking for subsets then you forget the ordering, so presumably you care about the indices of the elements. But the ordered set $[1,2,3,4,4,4]$ then has three possible splits: $[4]_{4},[4]_{5}$, $[4]_{4},[4]_{6}$, and $[4]_{5},[4]_{6}$ (by $[4]_{4}$ I mean the $[4]$ on the $4$-th place).

Comment: Oh, I forgot about another splitting option.
You understood my question correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use word split here, because this word implies that each element goes to one of parts (multisets in your case). So you are given a sequence $(a_i)_{i = 1}^n$ and need to find the number of unordered pairs of two non-intersecting sets of indices that imply equal multisets of elements. Also as far as I see you the index sets to be non-empty. Formally you need to find
$$b = |\{\,\{\,\{\,i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{\ell}\,\}, \{\,j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{\ell}\,\}\,\} \mid \{\,a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, \ldots, a_{i_{\ell}}\,\} = \{\,a_{j_1}, a_{j_2}, \ldots, a_{j_{\ell}}\,\}\land \{\,i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{\ell}\,\} \cap \{\,j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{\ell}\,\}\,\} = \varnothing \land \{\,i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_{\ell}\,\} \ne \varnothing \,\}|.$$
For simplicity we allow the pair of empty index sets and will count the number of ordered pairs of index sets. At the end we will subtract this pair and divide the number by $2$ to switch to the number of unordered pais.

If you have $f(x) = |\{\, i \mid a_i = x\,\}|$ equal elements $x$ in your sequence then you have $\binom{f(x)}{k}$ ways to select a index set with $k$ elements. From the remaining $f(x) - k$ elements $x$ you can select $k$ other indices for the second set in $\binom{f(x) - k}{k}$ ways. Therefore for the elements $x$ you have
$$\sum_k \binom{f(x)}{k}\binom{f(x) - k}{k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor f(x)/2 \rfloor} {f(x)! \over k!^2 (f(x) - 2k)!}$$
ways to select an ordered pair of sets of indices. These choices are independent for different $x$. Therefore the total number of ordered pairs is
$$\prod_x \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor f(x)/2 \rfloor} {f(x)! \over k!^2 (f(x) - 2k)!}.$$
Now we need subtract pair of empty sets and divide the number of ordered pairs (of two definitely distinct elements each) by $2$ to get the number of unordered pairs:
$$b = \left(\left(\prod_x \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor f(x)/2 \rfloor} {f(x)! \over k!^2 (f(x) - 2k)!}\right) - 1\right) \cdot \frac12.$$